# Previewing data from a step containing binary file is very slow in PDI

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

I am using Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) to migrate files from PostgreSQL to mongoDB. While I´m designing the ETL I often need to preview the data that is going through the flow to verify that everything is correct. When I try to preview the data,  PDI takes a long time to show me the data because it tries to show the binary data.
Is there any way to optimize this in PDI version 9.0?
[image]

Comment: Are you putting limit while previewing the data? 
For-Example : if your input has 10,000 record and if you are doing preview just for logic verification purpose, in this case keeping preview limit to 5 or 10 will solve your problem.

Comment: I´m using a single sample record.

Comment: ok, 
Component level you can't do anything.
Allocate more RAM to PDI and see if that gives performance improvement.